# Use of LINQ and ArrayList

Tags: c#, linq

I've recently used LINQ

In the following code:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
var myStrings = list.AsQueryable().Cast<string>();
```

What is the `AsQueryable` for? I know `Cast` creates a type-safe collection, and `ArrayList` is deprecated.

I've got a friend who says he needs the `AsQueryable` combined with `ArrayList`. I'm trying to understand why, but I can't see why `AsQueryable` is needed.

Is he wrong?

Comment: @thecoop great translation job. if only there was some way to award points for that :)

Comment: THANK YOU to stack for many answer of use !! i will put link to answer to associat.. arraylist is for OLD !! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsQueryable would be used to produce an IQueryable which can then, if implemented, analyse the query via expression trees to rewrite it or translate it into some other language-like with linq to sql for example.

In this case it is completely pointless and you can tell your friend not to bother.

Answer (score 13):

You do not need the call to `AsQueryable()`. Queryables only make sense when a LINQ query (expressed in C#) needs to be converted to another domain language (such as SQL). In your case since you are working with LINQ to Objects (you are operating on an array list) this is not needed.

You can call the `Cast<T>()` method directly on the list instance. Another choice would be to start with a strongly-typed collection such as `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The only effect the use of `AsQueryable()` has here is to make the static type of the result of the query is `IQueryable<string>`.  For all intents and purposes, this is really useless on an object.

You only really need:

```
var myStrings = list.Cast<string>();
```

without the `AsQueryable()`.  Then the type of the result is just `IEnumerable<string>`.

Or better yet, to get a strongly typed `List<string>`:

```
var myStrings = list.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Comment: AsQueryable has no effect only if the source is already an IQueryable... if it's not, it creates an IQueryable wrapper